# decorators to pass numpy arrays or xarray arrays to functions

Tags: python-xarray

Do you have any examples of convenience decorators that might allow functions that take numpy-like arrays to pass in xarray DataArrays and ensure that the metadata is maintained?

In short, I would like to pass in either numpy arrays or xarrays to my functions, without adding the logic to the function definition that preserves the metadata.

Two simple examples that I can point to in OSS are functions like `rgb2gray` and `img_as_*` in scikit-image. `img_as_*` is particular simple since the only thing that changes is the dtype (and the units)

```
  import xarray as xr
  import numpy as np
  c = np.zeros([3, 3, 3])
  c_xr = xr.DataArray(c, dims=['y', 'x', 'rgb'])
  from skimage import img_as_ubyte
  print(img_as_ubyte(c_xr))  # this is a numpy array
```

If those decorators exist in the library, could you point me to them? If you have an example implementation that you use for your own projects, do you mind pointing me to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you can make a decorator that simply calls [`xarray.apply_ufunc()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#wrapping-custom-computation). This lets you reuse the same wrapping code that xarray uses internally.

For example:

```
import functools
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

def enable_xarray_wrapper(func):
    """Adds an xarray wrapper for a function without core dimensions."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return xr.apply_ufunc(func, *args, kwargs=kwargs)
    return wrapper

@enable_xarray_wrapper
def xarray_safe_img_as_ubyte(array):
    return img_as_ubyte(array)

c = np.zeros([3, 3, 3])
c_xr = xr.DataArray(c, dims=['y', 'x', 'rgb'])

print(xarray_safe_img_as_ubyte(c))  # this is a numpy.ndarray
print(xarray_safe_img_as_ubyte(c_xr))  # this is an xarray.DataArray
print(xarray_safe_img_as_ubyte(xr.Dataset({'foo': c_xr})))  # this is an xarray.Dataset
```